# Display references

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

When displaying bibliography, I want when I get a new line, the new line is offset by three letters of the first line. Fo example here :

> Lio W, Jaroszewsk L, Godzik A (2001) Clustering of highly homologous sequences to reduce the size of large protein databases. Bioinformatics 17(3):282-283

I want that the letter t in the second line starts under letter o. Any help please

```
\documentclass{article}       
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{paralist}
 \makeatletter
 \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\bibsection\parindent\z@\begin{inparaitem}}
 {\end{inparaitem}}
 \makeatother
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
   colorlinks   = true,
   citecolor    = blue,
   linkcolor = blue,
   urlcolor=blue
  }
 \begin{document}
 \citealt{Lio2001}
 \begin{thebibliography}{99}
 \bibitem[Lio(2001)]{Lio2001} Lio W, Jaroszewsk L, Godzik A (2001) Clustering of 
  highly homologous sequences to reduce the size of large protein databases. 
  Bioinformatics 17(3):282-283.\\
  \bibitem[Lio(2000)]{Lio2000} Lio W, Jaroszewsk L, Godzik A (2000) Clustering of  highly homologous sequences to reduce the size of large protein databases. Bioinformatics 
  17(3):282-283.
  \end{thebibliography}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you seek?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
% following lines commented
% \usepackage{paralist}
% \makeatletter
% \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
% {\bibsection\parindent\z@\begin{inparaitem}}
% {\end{inparaitem}}
% \makeatother
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
   colorlinks   = true,
   citecolor    = blue,
   linkcolor = blue,
   urlcolor=blue
  }
 \begin{document}
 \citealt{Lio2001}
 \setlength{\bibsep}{-\baselineskip}    %%<------ added
 \begin{thebibliography}{}
 \bibitem[Lio(2001)]{Lio2001} Lio W, Jaroszewsk L, Godzik A (2001) Clustering of
  highly homologous sequences to reduce the size of large protein databases.
  Bioinformatics 17(3):282-283.\\
  \bibitem[Lio(2000)]{Lio2000} Lio W, Jaroszewsk L, Godzik A (2000) Clustering of  highly homologous sequences to reduce the size of large protein databases. Bioinformatics
  17(3):282-283.
  \end{thebibliography}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On the other hand, why don't you use `bibtex` with a proper style and let it do the work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much Harish Kumar. Its what I seek. About your proposition, I tried it before but  I had a problem with \cite, I have posted the question in this forum, but I haven't the answer, for that I use this solution